# Kill all child processes, but not the parent process

Tags: node.js, linux, shell

How can I kill all child processes, without killing parent process? I'm spawning multiple processes inside of my node script, I want to kill all of them and spawn new processes.

For now I found a `terminate` npm library which kills a parent process and all its children, but I don't want to kill the parent one, and the best solution would be to not use 3rd party libraries.

```
terminate(process.pid, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Could not kill processes");
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you keeping track of the child processes somehow?

Comment: Here's a documentation specific to node.js https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to deliver some signal that can be caught (not SIGKILL). Then, install a signal handler that detects if the current process is the parent process or not, and calls _exit() if it is not the parent process.

You could use SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2, or perhaps SIGQUIT.

I've illustrated this technique here.

Optionally (as suggested by Lidong), the parent process can use SIG_IGN on the signal before issuing the kill() command.

`signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
kill(-parent_pid, SIGQUIT);`